# To print output of SparkSQL to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently running Analyze command for particular table and could see the statistics being printed in the Spark-Console

However when I try to write the output to a DF I could not see the statistics.

**Spark Version : 1.6.3**

```
val a : DataFrame = sqlContext.sql("ANALYZE TABLE sample PARTITION (company='aaa', market='aab', edate='2019-01-03', pdate='2019-01-10') COMPUTE STATISTICS").collect()
```

**Output in spark Shell**

```
    Partition sample{company=aaa, market=aab, etdate=2019-01-03, p=2019-01-10} stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=215, totalSize=7551, rawDataSize=461390]
19/03/22 02:49:33 INFO Task: Partition sample{company=aaa, market=aab, edate=2019-01-03, pdate=2019-01-10} stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=215, totalSize=7551, rawDataSize=461390]
```

**Output of dataframe**

```
    19/03/22 02:49:33 INFO PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=runTasks start=1553237373445 end=1553237373606 duration=161 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
19/03/22 02:49:33 INFO PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=Driver.execute start=1553237373445 end=1553237373606 duration=161 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
19/03/22 02:49:33 INFO Driver: OK 
19/03/22 02:49:40 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
19/03/22 02:49:40 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2). 940 bytes result sent to driver
19/03/22 02:49:40 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2) in 4 ms on localhost (1/1)
19/03/22 02:49:40 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 2 (show at <console>:47) finished in 0.004 s
19/03/22 02:49:40 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 2.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
19/03/22 02:49:40 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 2 finished: show at <console>:47, took 0.007774 s
+------+
|result|
+------+
+------+
```

Could you please let me know how to get the same statistics output into the Dataframe.

Thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print from a Dataframe the way you are using, you can use,

```
val a : DataFrame = sqlContext.sql("ANALYZE TABLE sample PARTITION (company='aaa', market='aab', edate='2019-01-03', pdate='2019-01-10') COMPUTE STATISTICS")

a.select("*").show()
```